# Consulta en mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

Cómo puedo hacer una consulta en `mysql` que me permita:

- Contar registros repetidos por fecha.
- Luego dividir un valor entre ese total de registros repetidos por fecha.

**Ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces estoy buscando que la consulta ya sea en `mysql` con ayuda de `php` me permita dividir el tiempo entre la cantidad total de los equipos.

El resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

- Contar los equipos repetidos por fecha, como se muestra en el ejemplo
  el equipo: 600134 se repite 2 veces el 01/01/2019, entonces contar ese registro daría como resultado 2.
- Ahora tomar el primer tiempo de atención que seria el numero 1.
- Y luego dividir la cantidad de equipos contados que en un principio fueron 2/1.

Sería 2 registros contados repetidos el **01/01/2019** entre **1 = 0.5**.

Mi consulta actual esta así:

```
SELECT id,fecha,turno,flota,equipo,pos,razon,llanta,serial,programada,destino,grupo,diseno,tamano,compuesto,down_in,ti_attenequi,ti_downequi,COUNT(*) as id_down FROM tiempos 
GROUP BY equipo,pos,fecha order by fecha ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

Con esta consulta:

```
select fecha, equipo, count(*)
from tabla
group by fecha, equipo
having count(*) > 1
```

Te devuelve los equipos que tienen más de un registro en una fecha dada.

Luego con *PHP* puedes recorrer ese cursor y utilizarlo para calcular tu promedio.

Se podría pensar en alguna consulta más complicada, pero no tengo idea cuántos registros pueda tener la tabla para ver la eficiencia.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta ya lo probe pero me da error esa consulta.

Comment: @estrada Deberías indicarle qué error te da, así le será más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

esta consulta te trae a cantidad de fechas repetidas, con la ayuda de php divides ese total con lo que necesitas.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Repetidos, fecha FROM test GROUP By fecha HAVING Repetidos > 1
```

o este es el calculo en el mismo sql 'en el 1 va el valor que deseas calcular'..

```
SELECT (1/COUNT(*)) CalculoRepetidos, fecha FROM test GROUP By fecha HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Buenas tardes eirc, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, igual me da error: Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\estrada\procesos\excel\reporte_tiempos.php on line 74, en esa linea 74 tengo: $toal=$res["ti_attenequi"]/$res["id_down"]; esas variables que es la división del tiempo de atención (ti_attenequi) entre el total de equipos.

Comment: ya lo probe mejor y se quito el error coloque lo siguiente: $toal=$res["ti_attenequi"]/$res["Repetidos"]; pero de igual forma al ver los registros de 6500 registros ahora solo me muestra 315 registros.

Comment: Es que la consulta filtra a la cantidad de fechas repetidas